# Print line based on pattern

Tags: awk, grep

I have data in format

```
A  ((!(A1+A2)))
B  (A1A2)
C  (A1+A2)
D  (!(A1+A2)B1)
E  (!A1+!A2)
F  ((A1+A2)+A3+A4)
G  ((A1A2)+(A3A4))
```

I want output as

```
C  (A1+A2)
F  ((A1+A2)+A3+A4)
G  ((A1A2)+(A3A4))
```

I want to get that line which has only `+`

I used

```
awk -F' ' '$2 ~ /\+/' file
```

But this is listing all the lines which has `!` along with `+` in them

Answer (score 2):

You should add 1 more condition to your code like following. You are already checking if 2nd field has `+` in it add an additional check if its NOT having `!` too and then you should get your expected output.

```
awk '$2!~/!/ && $2~/\+/'  Input_file
```

Also you need not to use `-F' '` option because by default itself `awk` uses space as a field separator for all lines, so I removed it from suggested code.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this awk that allows only `+` other than `(`, `)`, `_` and alphanumerics:

```sh
awk '$2 ~ /^[()_[:alnum:]]+\+[()+_[:alnum:]]+$/' file

C  (A1+A2)
F  ((A1+A2)+A3+A4)
G  ((A1A2)+(A3A4))
```